# Selecting content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/zk4pc/2/

I'm trying to get it so that everytime there is an element with the class "insert_name", the name is printed from the table.

Could you also help me make the selection more advanced (for instance only using the data from the first tr in the "client-profile" class?

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<body onload="printMsg()">
<div id="api_data" style="display:none;">
    <div class="client-profile">
        <div class="head icon-5">Customer Details</div>
        <table id="client-information">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">Name:</td>
                    <td class="color"><a href="/profile">Matthew Tester</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="dark">
                    <td class="left">E-mail:</td>
                    <td class="color">asdfg</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">Registration:</td>
                    <td class="color">2013-11-21</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="dark">
                    <td class="left">Status:</td>
                    <td class="color"><span class="active">Active</span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">Last Login Time:</td>
                    <td class="color" title="2014-05-28 11:43:46">1 hour ago</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="dark">
                    <td class="left">Last Login From:</td>
                    <td class="color">123.123.123.123</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left">Location:</td>
                    <td class="color">United Kingdom</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="insert_name"></div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
(function printMsg() {
    var node = document.getElementsByClassName('insert_name');
    node.innerHTML = $('[class*="color"]').eq(0).text();
})();
```

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/zk4pc/3/?

Comment: not sure why you want to use pure JS methods while you know about using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to insert the name rather than all of the content, this should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $('.insert_name').text($('td:contains("Name:")').next().text());
});
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8LKQ/

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is the closest so far, are you able to narrow it to only the "client-profile" class?

Comment: `$(function() {
    $('.insert_name').text($('.client-profile td:contains("Name:")').next().text());
});` Solved it for me!

Answer (score 3):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/A5V6w/)***

The issue is with your node selection. When you select by class name it returns an array of elements. Since you are only looking for the div with that class name, access the first index to reference it.

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('insert_name')[0];
```

*edit*

To make this iterate all of the nodes you could take this approach

```
 var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('insert_name');
 var text = $('[class*="color"]').eq(0).text();
 for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
  nodes[i].innerHTML = text;
 }
```

Alternatively, since jQuery is already included, you could remove the body's onload event and just use this

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/4m9HS/)***

```
$(function(){
 $('.insert_name').html($('[class*="color"]').eq(0).text());
});
```

To ensure this only acts on the `client-profile` class the selector would be

```
$('.insert_name').html($('.client-profile [class*="color"]').eq(0).text());
```

Comment: That's a great start :) , but I have multiple elements in the real thing with the "insert_name" class, and it only does the first one? Look here for an example: http://msdhosting.co.uk/cpanel/new/pages/profile.html

Comment: if you take out the [0] and you add .each(function( index, node){
node.innerHTML = $('[class*="color"]').eq(0).text();
});
This is shorthand so sorry if its not exact

Comment: @MStratford - Can you clarify that a little? As written it will modify each `.insert_name` element. Did you only want it to do the first?

Comment: @Joshua - The second version will at least. For the first you would need to iterate.

Comment: The Alernative method here works nicely, however is there the posibility of you being about to narrow it to the first "colour" class of only the "client-profile" class?

Comment: @MStratford - On your page, there is only one div marked client_profile. However, you could use `.client-profile [class*="color"]` in order to select that. `$('.insert_name').html($('.client-profile [class*="color"]').eq(0).text());`

Answer (score 1):

I added a little more jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('[class*="color"]').each(function(){
        $('.insert_name').append($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zk4pc/7/
Hope that helps!

Comment: This repeats, but it now copies everything with "colour" from that table, not just the first one (the name). I would like it to print "Matthew Tester" in each occurrence of the "insert_name" div.

Comment: Nice :) But I think that @mifi79 has the answer for me, just would like that other class filter implemented for perfection...